# Error while trying to run project in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a Windows Form application and trying to debug it.
It displays the following error:

> error while trying to run project could not load file or assembly or
>   one of its dependencies

I updated and repaired my Visual Studio but error is same.
When I go to bin\debug and try to run .exe it shows this error:

> the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Comment: You are missing one of the required assemblies in your project. Show us some more details and we can help you better.

Comment: Check for the name of the assembly if you can see it in the build error or console window.

Comment: If remember well, 0xc000007b means that you it's trying to load an assembly with a different target from the running one.
Probably, you are running an x64 application that is trying to load an x86 assembly.
You can try to open your .exe with Dependency Walker and check if one ore more of the dependencies have a different target. Anyway, you will probably need to repair your .NET Framework

Comment: How can i checked assembly name give me details i did found anything like that

Comment: @ChathurangaEdirisingha 
So probably is the opposite: You compiled an x86/AnyCPU application that is trying to load an x64 assembly. Or you compilation target is x64

Comment: @codroipo how can i checked my compilation target or assembly

Comment: @ChathurangaEdirisingha does your solution name or assembly names have apostrophy symbol..i got this erorr for this..

Comment: @ChathurangaEdirisingha I posted as answer to be more clear

Comment: @Sachu How can i checked my assembly name

Comment: @ChathurangaEdirisingha: Check if you missing anything using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: @ChathurangaEdirisingha `go to the build and click clean solutions`.Try this.

Answer (score 0):

0xc000007b means STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, this is an indication that your x86 application tries to load an x64 dll, or that your application target is x64, to check this you can look in the Project properties->Build->Target Platform
[image: Platform Target Checking]

If your platform target is not x64 you can check your application dependencies with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) and look if one or more of them is a 64 bit dll.